# ingress with DMZ on on-premise infrastructure

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, haproxy, dmz

i have a question related to design and architecture needs instead of issue one, we have a kubernetes cluster which handle our production workload, we need to secure external traffic to this cluster so we have designed this approach :

- make a worker node with ingress controller and without any workload
- place this worker node in a DMZ zone in order to handle external traffic to our clusterIP services of our applications.

is that a good idea for securing our workloads ?

if we place an HAproxy in a DMZ zone (as a L4 just to load balance traffic to workers to be handled by ingress nginx for ex) it'll not give us an other level of security (protocol break)

note that we don't have a WAF.
Any ideas please??

Comment: I believe that you should consider contacting Google Sales and speak with a Solutions Architect

Comment: @DerekFender i hope to get a reply from someone who know exactly how to expose ingress in on premise clusters

Comment: @DerekFender why Google Sales and not any other company out there which have Solution Architects for Kubernetes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree to use two dedicated nodes, for high availability, for external traffic entry point.

I would use the haproxy ingress controller [Announcing HAProxy Kubernetes Ingress Controller 1.6](https://www.haproxy.com/blog/announcing-haproxy-kubernetes-ingress-controller-1-6/) with [Evolving Kubernetes networking with the Gateway API](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2021/04/22/evolving-kubernetes-networking-with-the-gateway-api/)